# Where did this loading image come from?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8.1, icons

This is an image I have had for a while, and I want to know where it came from. I believe it came from windows so if you can point me towards the right dll/folder I'd really appreciate it!

[image]

Comment: When will it be shown?

Comment: It is not a part of Windows itself. It must have come from some other program.  https://goo.gl/t5KHBn

Comment: I could have sworn I got it off of windows. I am trying to find the original file because I changed it to a .ico to use as a custom drive icon. However, I would like to edit it and cant now that it's an icon. Thanks anyway.